# Magento - Please specify the product required option(s) Error in configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9

I got below error on the configurable product of Magento 1 website. I have tried with http and https but it's not working.

```
Please specify the product required option(s)
```

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On Admin please go into the product and check of you have any custom options added. If custom options are added, the customer might need to checkbox those options on the front-end to continue to checkout.